# "alone" vs. "by myself" vs. "on my own"

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase-usage

As a German speaker, I'm surprised to hear *by myself/yourself/himself...* or *on my/your/his... own* where I would have expected the word *alone* or *myself/yourself/himself...* (without *by*). Meanwhile, I even started to doubt if I ever should use the word *alone* in English. But on the other side, the English word *alone* exists, so it must be idiomatic in **some** cases.

So, my question is:
When to use the word *alone*?
When to use *by myself/yourself...*?
When to use *on my/your... own*?

Answer (score 1):

(I thought I had answered this question or one like it, but can't find any trace of it.)

You can use any of those expressions to mean that you have nobody else with you.

*Alone* can also mean that you are the only person to whom something has happened - "I alone survived the accident."

*On my own* can also mean that you did something without help - "I found the answer on my own."